# SQL Trigger Causing Error 1054

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER Discount
BEFORE INSERT ON ORDER_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE OrderNum INT;
    DECLARE Membership BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE Disc DECIMAL(10, 2);
    DECLARE Cost DECIMAL(10, 2);

    SELECT OrderCount INTO OrderNum
    FROM Customer
    WHERE CustomerID = NEW.CustomerID;

    SELECT Member INTO Membership
    FROM Customer
    WHERE CustomerID = NEW.CustomerID;

    SELECT Discount INTO Disc
    FROM Order_Table
    WHERE OrderID = NEW.OrderID;

    SELECT Price INTO Cost
    FROM Order_Table
    WHERE OrderID = NEW.OrderID;

    IF(Membership = TRUE) THEN
        IF(MOD(OrderCount, 10) = 0) THEN
            SET NEW.Discount = Cost/2;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END//
delimiter;
```

Above is a trigger for the database I am writing for a dry cleaning store. The trigger is supposed to make it so that every customer that has a membership at the dry cleaning store receives a discount with every 10th order they make. However when we enter the following data

```
insert into order_table values(0, 1, curdate(),20140426, null , 100, 10, 0, 110);
```

We get error 1054: Unknown column OrderCount in field list even though OrderCount exists in the customer table

Comment: Show us the structure of Customer table... possibly try to recreate it on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
 CustomerID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
 LastName varchar(45) not null,
 FirstName varchar(45) not null,
 Email varchar(255),
 Address varchar(45),
 State varchar(45),
 Zip varchar(5),
 OrderCount int not null,
 Member boolean,
 PRIMARY KEY CUSTOMER_PK(CustomerID)
);

Comment: I dislike doing this as a trigger, I'd rather get the information before hand.  For one thing, triggers can be turned off (and then forgotten).  I'd also rather count the records in `Order_Table` (with the appropriate condition to not count/disallow for unpaid orders) - as it is, customers can create multiple (unprocessed) orders that would receive a discount.  Besides the fact that the first order is discounted, and comes every 10 starting with order **11**.  For preference, I'd want a separate `Discount` table that I could add it to, for flexibility.  What's assigning the `OrderID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the error message is coming from using OrderCount in the if block. You should be using the variable you declared and read this value into, OrderNum.

The other problem you might have, which I can't tell from this design, is when the Order Number is being updated. It might be best to add this to the trigger, so that the count of orders in the Customer tables is increased by one with the trigger, which can then be checked.

I just added this line to the trigger (after the variable declarations):

```
UPDATE `customer` SET `OrderCount`=OrderCount+1 WHERE `CustomerID`=NEW.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I work with oracle and it's quite different, but reading your trigger i suggest you , to  rewrite the 4 querys to 2, this way you can avoid read each table twice.

.:
.:

```
.:
 SELECT OrderCount, Member 
    INTO OrderNum, Membership
    FROM Customer
    WHERE CustomerID = NEW.CustomerID;

    SELECT Discount, Price 
    INTO Disc, Cost
    FROM Order_Table
    WHERE OrderID = NEW.OrderID;
```

.:
.:
.:

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in MySQL 5.6.17 on triggers when you reference another table that has been truncated: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72446

Maybe that's the reason?  I'm trying to work around this by changing my TRUNCATE table_name to DELETE FROM table_name.  (Also, the bug report seems to indicate that this is fixed in MySQL 5.6.19, but I haven't tested this yet.)